# Settings for application after release

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I have a winforms (C#) application in which will have some settings I want to modify after its built.

I am thinking of a simple XML file with properties like:

```
 <Settings>
    <Username>MyUsername</Username>
    <RealName>MyRealName</RealName>
  </Settings>
```

These values should I be able to change after its released as a exe file. Maybe in a XML file stored next to it. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but using app.config is preferable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look at `app.config` - this is precisely for this purpose.

See the MSDN reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658(v=vs.80).aspx

In particular check the `<appSettings>` section.

Comment: See also http://codehill.com/2009/01/saving-user-and-application-settings-in-winforms/

Comment: I now have the App.Config file and I used the values from it. Should this file then be set to "Copy to Output Directory"?

Comment: No need to do that - the system will do that (and rename it to <your application name>.exe.config automatically on a build.

Comment: Problem if i change it after its built - the application wont start? Only if it has the values it was built with. :-(